# Problem on accessing array elements by index

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js, ejs

I am trying to generate a generic HTML table in which the column names and the content changes depending on the selection.
I was expecting to access array elements by id but apparently it is not working properly.

Here is my code:

```
<% records.forEach(function(record){ %>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <% for (var i = 0; i < noOfCols; i++) { %>
        <td tabindex="0"><%= record[i] %></td>
   <% } %>                                        
        <td nowrap="">
            <span class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="btn m-btn m-btn--hover-brand m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                  <i class="la la-ellipsis-h"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="la la-edit"></i> Edit Details</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="la la-leaf"></i> Update Status</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="la la-print"></i> Generate Report</a>
                </div>
            </span>
                <a href="#" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-brand m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="View">
                    <i class="la la-edit"></i>
                </a>
        </td>
</tr> <% }); %>
```

`<%= record[i] %>` is returning `null` unfortunately.

Here is my app.js code block to route to the page:

```
app.get('/edit/:tblId', async function(req, res, next) {
console.log("***************** Edit Table *******************");

const allDatabases  = await dbInstance.genericQuery(dbQueries.allDbSQL);
const allTables     = await dbInstance.genericQuery(dbQueries.allTbSQL);

const singletable   = await dbInstance.genericQuery(dbQueries.singleTableSQL.replace('{tblId}', req.params.tblId));
const tableName     = await dbInstance.getTableName(req.params.tblId);
const columnNames   = await dbInstance.genericQuery(dbQueries.headersTbSQL.replace('{tblId}', req.params.tblId));

const records       = await dbInstance.getTableRecords(tableName);
const noOfCols      = await dbInstance.genericQuery(dbQueries.headersTbSQL.replace('col.column_name', 'count(1) colNo').replace('{tblId}', req.params.tblId));

console.log('SQL: ' + dbQueries.headersTbSQL.replace('col.column_name', 'count(1) colNo').replace('{tblId}', req.params.tblId))

console.log('noOfCols: ' + noOfCols[0].colNo);
console.log(records);
res.render('edit_table_new', {
    parameters: arrayOpsInstance.getMatchDBWithTables(allDatabases, allTables),
    tblName: tableName,
    pagePathDatabase: 'EDIT DATA - ' + singletable[0].database_name.toUpperCase(),
    pagePathSchema: singletable[0].schema_name.toUpperCase(),
    tableDesc: singletable[0].table_desc,
    headers: columnNames,
    records: records,
    noOfCols: Number(noOfCols[0].colNo)
});
```

});

And here is the records array:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
database_id: 1,
database_name: 'REFERA',
organization_id: 1,
database_type_id: 3,
database_alias: 'Refera Repository',
database_desc: 'Holds Refera Repository Information',
ip_number: 'localhost',
port_number: '3306',
service_name: 'refera',
username: 'uuu',
password: 'ppp' },
```

RowDataPacket {
    database_id: 2,
    database_name: 'MAKEIT Tables',
    organization_id: 1,
    database_type_id: 1,
    database_alias: 'MAKEIT Temp Tables',
    database_desc: 'Holds MAKEIT Temp Tables',
    ip_number: 'localhost',
    port_number: '1521',
    service_name: 'XE',
    username: 'uuu',
    password: 'ppp' } ]

I do appreciate if you can help (I am using NodeJS and prefer generate HTML phrases within HTML file rather than calculating in script).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the framework you're using. `<%= %>` is used by a number of them.

Comment: Thanks Heretic Monkey, I have stated that I am using NodeJS..

Comment: Okay but what templating engine are you using? NodeJS is the javascript runtime environment, not the library that is giving you the `<%= %>` syntax.

Comment: I use ejs if you are asking that..

Comment: See how I edited your question to include the `node.js` tag? You can do that with the name of the framework...

Comment: You're already looping an array called `records` - is `record` actually an array? do you mean `records[i]`?

Comment: It's not node related

Comment: @user7438092 Yes, ejs is the library you are using for generating markup. As Aluan said, this is not related to NodeJS.

Comment: @user7438092 please replace `record[i]` with just `i` and tell us what the result was

Comment: Replying tymeJV: records[i] does not work, records is already an array of array. If I do so each cell includes [object object]...

Comment: Replying Amir: if I put i instead of record[i], cells show the value of i such as 1,2,3.. etc. if I write lets say record.column_name then all cells are filled with value of the column_name.. Shorty, this does not work as well..

Comment: @user7438092 Then I assume `record` is not an array, or if it is, the indexes are not incremental numbers (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...). (As you may know, in javascript indexes of arrays can be what ever you want)

Comment: @user7438092 can you show us the app.js route for this page and can you post the results of `console.log(records);` on your app.js please?

Comment: To answer your question we need to know what kind of data we are working with (ie what records looks like)

Comment: Amir, record is just a single record. If I was coding as <td tabindex="0">record.name</td> eveything would be fine. But since I am trying to produce a generic HTML table I needed to use indexes instead of actual column_names..

Comment: @user7438092, please post the result of `console.log(record);`
If `record` has a `name` property, it is very likely not an array, or as I said it is an array with weird indexes. This is probably why you get `null` for `record[i]`

Comment: I have added the app.js block and the records array...

Comment: Just to let you know guys, Amir's recommendation using for(let prop in obj){
    //access values with obj[prop]
} solved my problem. Thanks a lot Amir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items in `records` array are not array themselves (`RowDataPacket`). They are objects and hence you can't iterate through them with this kind of `for loop` as you did.
You can iterate over object keys using

```
for(let prop in obj){
    //access values with obj[prop]
}
```